# Laurent Expansion Theory

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

If $f$ has a Laurent expansion like this:

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty} ^{\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$$

in the annulus $r < |z-z_0|<\infty$, then, I need to prove that the function $f$ can also be represented like this:

$$ f(z)= \sum_{n = -\infty} ^{\infty} \overline a_n z^n $$

in an annulus $\overline r < |z| < \infty$ for some $r$.

At first, I did not know what the variables with underlines meant. However, when reading my notes again, I found another reference as to when they were used. It lies in the proof of this theorem:

> A function given by a power series at $z_0$ with $R$ as its radius of convergence has at least one singular point on the circle $|z-z_0| = R$

The proof involves letting $f$ be a Taylor series on a disc of convergence $K = {|z-z_0|<R}$, and considering each point on the circular boundary of the disc $\Gamma$ to be regular w.r.t. $(f,K)$. Then, we should take a union of all circles $K_a$ with $K$ such that

$$ \overline K = K \cup \bigcup_{a \in \Gamma} K_a $$

Would the $\overline a_n$ and $\overline r$ be defined in a similar way? If so, how? If not, how can I move forward with the proof?

Comment: No, they are not defined similar, but in all three cases, the overline (underlines are *under*, overlines are *over*) just indicates another variable for which the same letter is being used because it bears some relationship to the original. In this case, it is no different from adding a subscript. $\overline a_n$ and $\overline r$ are just additional variables. You could call them $b_n$ and $s$ if you prefer.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, so they're not complex conjugates or anything?

Comment: Not in this case. It is just another variable related to the first one. I agree that this is confusing. I only know that this is the correct interpretation by context. But note that $r$ is real, so it doesn't make sense to talk about $\overline r$ as something distinct. You give the definition for $\overline K$, so there is no doubt what it means. And $\overline a_n$ cannot mean the conjugate - if it did, then no such representation of $f$ would exist,